# Replace XProcessingInstruction from XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a case where a user uploads an XML file.  I am using XDocument to handle it.  However, I want to replace the stylesheet used with one on the server.  Is there a way to use XDocument to modify the

I can get the expression with linq, as an XmlNode, as shown below:

```
var node = from proc in doc.Nodes()
           where proc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction
           select proc;
```

But I cannot figure out how to replace the node.

Update:  I feel like an idiot...

```
var node = doc.Nodes().Where(type => type.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction).Single() as XProcessingInstruction;
node.Data = "href=\"" + Utilities.Utility.XSLLocation + "\" type=\"text/xsl\"";
```

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`XNode.ReplaceWith` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.replacewith.aspx).

Comment: Please, close the question if you found solution